# Have I proved that the series diverges by the limit test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have to find out whether the following series diverges.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{1/k}}
$$
I thought that it would be correct if I just write something like this:
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{1/k}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^k=A \\
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&A = \lim_{k_1\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^{2k_1}=1 \\
&A = \lim_{k_2\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^{2k_2-1}=-1
\end{aligned}\Rightarrow\nexists A\Rightarrow \text{the initial series diverges.}
\right.
$$
Am I right here?

Comment: The term test is not met so the series diverges, right?

Comment: Well, if the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges than $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k=0$. Here $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k\ne 0$ hence the series diverges.

Comment: So, my solution is ok then?

Comment: Well, English is not my native language. Thank you, anyway!

Comment: it's very good relatively then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have exactly the right idea! The Divergence Test says that if the summand approaches *anything* other than $0$ (or does not exist) then the series diverges. You were able to see that the limit tends to something that flips between $-1$ and $1$ (which is not $0$) and therefore diverges by the Divergence Test.

These cases can be tricky to write up, so while your write-up may be acceptable to some, it may not be to others. For example, to say $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^{1/k}}= \lim_{k \to \infty} (-1)^k$ you either need to write more, or have taken the limit without really having taken the limit. [After all, how else did the $k^{1/k}$ term vanish?!] So a write-up like below would be cleaner:

For a limit to exist, it must exist 'any way you go to infinity'.

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{2k}}{(2k)^{1/(2k)}}= \lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{(2k)^{1/(2k)}}= \dfrac{1}{1}=1
$$
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^{1/(2k+1)}}=\lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{-1}{(2k+1)^{1/(2k+1)}}= -1
$$
Therefore, the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^{1/k}}$ does not exist so that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^{1/k}}$ diverges by the Divergence Test.

Comment: *You were able to see that the limit tends to something that flips between $-1$ and $1$...* Actually, the sequence tends to no definite value.

Comment: @Allawonder We are saying the exact same thing. For example, I would also say that $(-1)^n \dfrac{n}{n+1}$ or $(-1)^n (1+1/n)$ both tend to something that flips between $-1$ and 1. Yes, both limits do not exist, but we can say more about *how* they do not exist. This is more a difference in perspective but I find it works well with the students I teach.

Comment: To be clear, my quibble is simply about the phrase *tends to something* used to describe something that *fails to tend to anything.* That's a contradiction in terms, and should not be used for any reason.

Comment: @Allawonder I completely understand the quibble, and since I did not give the OP a whole spiel on exactly what I mean by this, it is not optimal. Again, I find this works with students who want to say the limit is the same as $\lim_{k \to \infty} (-1)^k$ but do not give proper justification, as per the OP. I would rather they say what I did, then write that.

Comment: Note there are places where we do say something tends to something without a limit. For example, the number of primes $\leq X$ tends to $X/\log X$ as $X \to \infty$, despite this having no real valued limit. Moreover, $\left\{(-1)^k/k^{1/k} \right\}$ does tend to $\{(-1)^n\}$ in measure, defining these as step functions in the appropriate way, not that this has much to do with the matters at hand.

Comment: I won't pursue this much further, although I still claim one should not use such phrases, no matter for what reason. As for your claim that about $x/\log x$ at infinity. Of course this does tend to something, namely $+\infty.$ On the other hand, a sequence like $(-1)^n$ does not tend to anything. My point has nothing to do with infinite limits. A function can tend to positive or negative infinity -- that's very different from saying the function has no limit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right, since for a series to converge, it is necessary that its terms tend to nothing.

But as you've rightly calculated, the terms of your series above do not go to zero.